# Is it possible to use IF statements in PROC IMPORT?

Tags: sas

I'm importing a data set in Stata format using PROC IMPORT, but I'd like to use IF statements to create a few new variables as well. However, simply using code like this returns an error of "ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order." :

```
PROC IMPORT
    DATAFILE = "myfile.dta"
    DBMS = DTA
    OUT = mydata
    REPLACE;
IF close < 10 THEN val = "low";
ELSE val = "high";
RUN;
```

I don't see any code for a data step generated in my log file either, even if I use ODS TRACE ON. Is there another way to use IF statements here?

UPDATE: If I add a DATA step after the PROC IMPORT, as shown:

```
PROC IMPORT
        DATAFILE = "myfile.dta"
        DBMS = DTA
        OUT = mydata
        REPLACE;
RUN;

DATA mydata;
    IF close < 10 THEN val = "low";
    ELSE val = "high";
RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA=mydata;
RUN;
```

This only prints out an empty table like this:

```
close | val
      | high
```

and inspecting the dataset shows that it doesn't contain any of the original data.

Comment: Just do a data step immediately after the proc import....

Comment: @CarolinaJay65 How would that DATA step be structured? Do I still need an INFILE statement in that DATA step? If I just put a DATA step with an IF statement, it appears to delete the data (see my edit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have stated, you cannot use an `if` statement inside of a `proc import`.  You are on the right track by placing the `if` inside a subsequent data step - you just had your syntax a little wrong.  It should look like this:

```
DATA mydata2;    /* A NEW DATASET CALLED MYDATA2 WILL BE CREATED. NOTE THERE IS NO EQUALS SIGN */
    set mydata;  /* IT WILL BE BASED OFF THE MYDATA DATASET */
    IF close < 10 THEN val = "low";
    ELSE val = "high";
RUN;
```

Comment: Perfect. This does exactly what I need. The SET keyword is what I hadn't found in my search of the documentation (a fault of my own, not the documentation, I'm sure).

Answer (score 1):

You can never use IF in a SAS procedure. IF belongs into a data step.

**update**

```
proc import ...;
run;

data mydata;
set mydata;
length val $4; **ensure right length;
if close<10 then val='low';
else val='high';
run;
```

Comment: Is there not a way to create new variables when I import a dataset, then? Since the log doesn't show any generated code, I can't simply copy the generated DATA step and use IF statements there, but I need to create new variables after the data set is imported.

Comment: you can do an infile in a data step and then in the same data step apply the if. or you need to run the if in a new data step after proc import. you can also run the import wizard which will generate the infile data step for you.

Comment: Could you give me an example of that? I'm not sure from [the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/a000146932.htm#a000209366) how to use INFILE to read Stata files.

Comment: ok sorry, for stata files it's not possible as they are not delimited, for csv etc it does work. why is doing if in data step such an issue?

Comment: Right, I'm specifically referring to Stata files. I need to use IF because I need to create a new variable based on the results of a condition. In a DATA step (literally, a step using the DATA keyword and the INFILE keyword, for example), I would use IF statements to accomplish this, but since I can't use IF statements in PROC IMPORT, I need another way. If not in the PROC IMPORT statement, where would I create new variables?

Comment: Long story short, I need to create new variables based on data imported *from a Stata file* using PROC IMPORT. How do I do this?